# How can I perform a wildcard search on a vertex property in titan graph DB?

Tags: database, graph, elasticsearch, titan

I am using blueprints api to query titan graph database. I am in a situation where I need to perform wild card search on a vertex property. Is there a way to query a vertex with its property with a wildcard? something similar to "PropertyName like '%asdf%' " in relational database.

Answer (score 4):

You can read about how to do string-based searches here:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Full-Text-and-String-Search#string-search

In your case you would likely need to use a `Text.REGEX` based search as you want to evaluate both sides of the string.  You would execute this with the Blueprints API using the Query API and would be something like:

```
graph.query().has("name",Text.REGEX,".*asdf.*").vertices()
```

Comment: What are '.query()' and '.vertices()'? They're not in Gremlin docs.

Comment: That's not "Gremlin" - it's a raw graph query from Blueprints: http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.6.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/Query.html

Comment: anything changed over 5 years? or this is limited to Titan? 

I am doing something wrong or its not working with tinkerpop3 + neo4j v3     .........  *gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 597: No such property: Text for class: Script16*

Comment: TinkerPop still does not natively support full text search

Answer (score 1):

In Gremlin v2 I do this:

```
g.v.has('name',REGEX,'.*asdf.*').map
```